# How to make my users able to add custom domain with React.js+Node App

Tags: reactjs, dns, subdomain

Im using React.js and Nodejs as an api, my nodejs is hosted on some server and my React.js app is hosted on netlify, i want my users to be able to add their custom domain or subdomain pointing to their profile

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Nope :( if you found something please dont hesitate to come back here